# add to log when user logged in

Tags: bash, unix, logging

I want to save in a log when a user just logged in to the `UNIX` server.
I thought to do it with a script that searches for changes on every 10 seconds.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with `/var/log/wtmp`? Why don't use an existing log?

Comment: I need to echo when someone logged in + log it. can it be done with that log?

Comment: @gdoron: what do you mean by echo? Do you need to have process continually writing some output? You could use some of the newer incarantions of syslog to log any login event to a seprate file, if you like that better.